# Как перевести строку в нормальную кодировку?

Tags: python, строки, кодировка

У меня в данных могут попадаться строки такого типа

```
Р? РµС‰Рµ РѕРґРёРЅ С„Р°
```

Как перевести их в читабельный вид в python?

Comment: Нужно смотреть откуда у вас такой текст приходит

Comment: из файла Эксель. Там есть и нормальный текст и попадается вот такой. Все находится в одном столбце

Answer (score 0):

Есть отличный метод decode()

Будет это все так

```
s = 'Р РµС‰Рµ РѕРґРёРЅ С„Р°'
decoded_s = s.encode('cp1251').decode('utf-8')
print(decoded_s)
```

***Внимание спойлер***

Вывод - Еще один фа

Comment: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u0420' in position 0: ordinal not in range(256)

Comment: Поправил, теперь все гуд

Comment: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: invalid continuation byte

Comment: пойдем по долгому пути?)
Или попробуем самостоятельно кодировки поиска?)
у меня сработало

Comment: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: invalid continuation byte` кодировка файла UTF-8, версия Python 3.6.